# Bootstrap: navbar does not come up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

What has gong wrong? Here is the error message displayed by IE 8:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; BOIE8;ENUSMSCOM)
Timestamp: Wed, 4 Feb 2015 11:53:49 UTC

Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js

Comment: Bootstrap is supported for IE8

Comment: It's not supported, but respond *will* work. You have to make sure you're not using a CDN for the Bootstrap elements cause otherwise you need to do a proxy to made Respond work. https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#cdnx-domain-setup